# org-mode clock sum to count 8h a day and not 24

Tags: org-mode

I'm using effort estimate with specification as `1d` or `4:00`, and these are correctly collected with the 8h a day in mind, but these are summed up the section hierarchy to count 24 hours a day.

Here's a very confusing `columnview`:

```
#+COLUMNS: %80ITEM(Tâche) %7Effort(Est){:}
#+BEGIN: columnview :maxlevel 2
| Tâche     |     Est |
|-----------+---------|
| * Group 1 |   16:00 |
| ** Task A |      1d |
| ** Task B |      1d |
| * Group 2 | 1d 0:00 |
| ** Task C |      1d |
| ** Task D |      2d |
#+END:
```

I would expect that `1d + 2d` would equal `3d`.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **org-time-clocksum-use-effort-durations** is a variable defined in `org.el`.
>
> Its value is **nil**
>
> When non-nil, M-x org-clock-display uses effort durations.
>   E.g. by default, one day is considered to be a 8 hours effort,
>   so a task that has been clocked for 16 hours will be displayed
>   as during 2 days in the clock display or in the clocktable.
>
> See `org-effort-durations` on how to set effort durations
>   and `org-time-clocksum-format` for more on time clock formats.

So:

```
(setq org-time-clocksum-use-effort-durations t)
```

Comment: "This variable is obsolete since Org 9.1; set `org-duration-units' instead."

Answer (score 3):

I have had success with the following on GNU Emacs 26.1, in combination with the [effort estimate](https://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html) instructions in the manual.

```
(setq org-duration-format '(("d" . nil) ("h" . t) ("min" . t)))

(setq org-effort-durations
      `(("min" . 1)
    ("h" . 60)
    ;; eight-hour days
    ("d" . ,(* 60 8))
    ;; five-day work week
    ("w" . ,(* 60 8 5))
    ;; four weeks in a month
    ("m" . ,(* 60 8 5 4))
    ;; work a total of 12 months a year --
    ;; this is independent of holiday and sick time taken
    ("y" . ,(* 60 8 5 4 12))))
```

Comment: In my org-mode version 9.1.9, it looks like `org-effort-durations` can still be customized, but it's never used by any of the org-mode code.  I set `org-duration-units` to that value instead, and now the summaries are adding up correctly.  Seems like `org-effort-durations` should have been deleted during a refactor.